# Can I somehow have static C macros?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to assign a value to a macro based on the value of another macro. However, the two macros are connected. Is there a way to avoid this? The following minimal example shows what I need:

```
#define VALUEA "A"
#define VALUEB "B"

// somewhere I define CHOOSE 
#define CHOOSE VALUEA

// MY_MACRO shall have the value of CHOOSE, but AT THE MOMENT of this line.
// I want to reassign CHOOSE while MY_MACRO stays the same.

#define MY_MACRO CHOOSE 
// now MY_MACRO has evaluates to CHOOSE evaluates to "A"

#define CHOOSE VALUEB
// now MY_MACRO has evaluates to "B" but I want it to be "A"
```

Comment: Can #define and #undef directives help in your scenario?

Comment: What you are asking is impossible, unless you define `MY_MACRO` as `VALUEA` directly.

Comment: Maybe? What happens if I undefine and redefine CHOOSE?

Comment: The same as without undefining, but eliminating a compiler warning at least ;)

Comment: I don't see how this makes any sense. If you need your program to change behavior over time, you need to use variables. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you undefine your macros, its undefined;) for example: if you #define VALUEA "A" followed by undef VALUEA is not defined anymore

Comment: Could you use a macro like: #define VALUEA "A"
                                             #define  VALUEB "B"                                                           #define MY_MACRO(x) x?VALUEA:VALUEB                  Note that you need the parameter x in this case.

Comment: Can you please explain use case scenario, I didn't understood your exact problem, (Note: You should true #if & #endif

Comment: you can use `#define static CHOOSE VALUEB` then you will get `MY_MACRO` as "A",  but it will hide `CHOOSE` and will show it as "A"

Answer (score 1):

Compiler will do the preprocessing whole project before compiling so if you do something like that it will lead to re-define macro warning and the `CHOOSE` always be what it is define latest.

You should separate the code in two mode similar to this:

```
#define VALUEA "A"
#define VALUEB "B"

#ifndef CASE_B
    #define CHOOSE VALUEA
#endif

#ifdef CASE_B
    #define CHOOSE VALUEB
#endif

#ifdef CASE_A
    #define MY_MACRO CHOOSE 
#endif
```

so you just need to define `CASE_A` or `CASE_B` according to your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial approach: "save" the "value" of a macro in a temporary macro:

```
#define VALUEA "A"
#define VALUEB "B"

#define CHOOSE VALUEA

#define MY_MACRO CHOOSE

// CHOOSE   -> VALUEA
// MY_MACRO -> VALUEA

#define TEMP MY_MACRO // save
#undef MY_MACRO

#define CHOOSE VALUEB
#define MY_MACRO TEMP // restore

// CHOOSE   -> VALUEB
// MY_MACRO -> VALUEA
```

Comment: Did you test this? It does not work. Neither `TEMP` nor `MY_MACRO` has a defined value after `#undef MY_MACRO`.